# Maximal subarray program implementation not terminating

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am trying to implement the algorithm for finding the maximum subarray sum in an array using the divide and conquer technique but for some reason the program doesn't terminate and I didn't manage to debug it successfully on my own. Can someone show me where the problem is?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int max_sub_arr(int arr[], int beginning, int end);
int helper_sub_arr(int arr[], int left, int center, int right);
int a[15] = {5, -2, 5, -6, 8, 20, -15, 4, 5, 3, -1, -2 , -5, 10, 1};
int length = 15;
int main()
{
    cout <<max_sub_arr(a, 0, length-1) << endl;
    return 0;
}
int max_sub_arr(int arr[], int beginning, int end)
{

    if(beginning == end) return arr[beginning];
    int center = (end - beginning)/2;
    int left = max_sub_arr(arr, beginning, center);
    int right = max_sub_arr(arr, center+1,end);
    int cross = helper_sub_arr(arr, left, center, right);

    if(left >= right && left >= cross) return left;
    else if(right >= left && right >= cross) return right;
    else return cross;

}
int helper_sub_arr(int arr[], int left, int center, int right)
{
    cout<<"as";
    int leftsum = -pow(2, 31);
    int rightsum = -pow(2, 31);
    int sum = 0;
    int maxleft, maxright;
    for(int i = center; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        sum += arr[i];
        if(sum > leftsum)
        {
            leftsum = sum;
            maxleft = i;
        }
    }
    sum = 0;

    for(int i = center + 1; i <= right; ++i)
    {
        sum += arr[i];
        if(sum > rightsum)
        {
            sum = rightsum;
            maxright = i;
        }
    }

    return maxleft + maxright;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `int center = (end - beginning)/2;` to `int center = (end + beginning)/2;`

After running I get segmentation fault at 50 line because the value of `right` variable was 72564.

Please read this http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/divide-and-conquer-maximum-sum-subarray/.

Comment: Thanks for the correction but again it doesnt terminate.